# Start Node server and run test in CICD

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, continuous-integration, supertest

I am currently trying to deploy some tests to Azure pipelines (but this should apply to any CICD framework)

I have an express project, and I am using `supertest` with `mocha` to run tests locally and everything is fine.

Now I want to deploy to production, and I want to run the tests in the pipeline before deployment happens.

The thing is that since these tests are running against http, they need a server running.

So, in my pipeline I have

`npm install
 npm start
 npm test`

But the thing is that `npm test` is not running when the server is started, but instead it just hangs in the server running.

Is there a way to start the tests when the server starts? and then stop the server when the tests are finished?

Or is there a better way to achieve all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using supertest I would suggest to export the express app for the tests instead of running it as shown in their docs, and then you would only need to run `npm install` and `npm test`.

For example:

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Add middlewares

module.exports = app;
```

test.spec.js

```
const app = require('../app.js');

request(app)
  .get('/user')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect(200)
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I had all that there.. But I didnt test in Azure.. I was just assuming.. Tried it and works. Another solution I came up with was to use pm2 to start the server in daemon mode. but of course it's better not to have to use an additional package just for that.